# c# sleeping thread problem

Tags: c#, multithreading, sleep

what is the problem in the code part below? Any ideas? I m sending command to my device through serial port. After each command the device will work for this command and then the other command comes for it and continues like this.

in Button Click event

```
{
  function1();
  Thread.Sleep(5000);
  function2();
  Thread.Sleep(5000);
  function3();
}
```

I figured out if i erase second sleep and function3 from the code like below, it does both two function but if i want to continue like this way it does not do the third one.

in Button Click event

```
{
  function1();
  Thread.Sleep(5000);
  function2();
}
```

works...
Thank you

Comment: This question is hard to understand, as there is no strict problem in the code posted (although there are usually better mechanisms than `Sleep`). It sounds like the problem is with the serial device, but you don't really make it clear what happens vs what you expect to happen. Not sure anyone can answer this based solely on the current information.

Comment: `what is the problem in the code` Please provide a self contained program demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Actually my scenario is to configure my device through serial port. For this purpose i need to send commands to my device. For example firstly i send first command "fdisk".My device take this copmmand and execute. and then i should send second command and wait for the device executes it and then send third. And my problem is sleeping the thread is not working for me.

Comment: Thread.Sleep(n); does work every single time, don't bother troubleshooting this as your source of error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're blocking the UI thread. *Don't do that.* It means your UI can't update itself. Instead, set a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` to fire in 5 seconds with the next function to call. Alternatively, do all of this in a different thread entirely (possibly using `Sleep`, possibly using another kind of timer to fire on a thread-pool thread) and use `Control.Invoke/BeginInvoke` to marshall back to the UI thread when you need to update the UI itself.

EDIT: Given your "answer", it seems that blocking the UI thread was only one of the problems - and getting the device to respond properly at all is a bigger problem. You shouldn't just rely on sleeping for a certain amount of time. You should detect when the device has completed the previous command. It's *possible* that it doesn't give any feedback, but that would be horrifically poor design. If at all possible, investigate how to read feedback from the device as to when it's finished (e.g. reading from the serial port!) and only start the next command when the previous one has finished. Depending on how you receive the feedback, you could use a blocking call on a non-UI thread, or use an asynchronous model to trigger things.

Comment: your a great supporter why not just nominate your self in the current moderation election?

Comment: @Rami: Because I think I serve the community better by answering questions.

Answer (score 0):

As the code is presented there it is nothing wrong with it. It will:

- Execute function 1
- Sleep 5 seconds
- Execute function 2
- Sleep 5 seconds
- Execute function 3

However since this is on a GUI event it will freeze the application while doing so. Consider spinning off the execution into a thread instead.

In .Net 4.0:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => sendData());
```

In all .Net versions:

```
System.Threading.Thread myThread = new System.Threading.Thread(sendData);
myThread.IsBackground = true;
myThread.Start();
```

And then you have your sendData method:

```
private void sendData()
{
  function1();
  Thread.Sleep(5000);
  function2();
  Thread.Sleep(5000);
  function3();
}
```

If you really need to do stuff in the GUI thread you can make it more responsive by regularly calling `Application.DoEvents();`, but this is not a good way of solving it.

Also remember that you can't access the GUI from other threads. See http://kristofverbiest.blogspot.com/2007/02/simple-pattern-to-invoke-gui-from.html for sample code on how to invoke the GUI thread from other threads.

Answer (score 0):

The BackgroundWorker might be a solution to solve the blocking of the UI.

Get rid of the Sleeps If the functions are creating their own threads, give them callback methods that trigger the next function after the first has finished.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you guys. I solve it. The problem is i did not make thread sleep enough. 5000 ms do not enough for the second command.

Comment: That is not a way to solve your problem. Use an other way of syncing (callback, Mutex, ...)

Comment: Yes right, this is a bad approach to solve the problem. There might be cases when 5secs might be less for the device to respond. You should use Aysnc Programming model. Does the types which interface with the device have Beingxxx, Endxxx methods? use them. If not use a System.Threading.Timer class to periodically check on the state of the device.

Comment: @user587674: I agree with the other comments. Sleeping for longer and hoping that it's long enough is *not* a good approach - particularly if the sleep is on the UI thread.